# Is there a way to disable item bonding so they can be freely tradable?

Tags: items, azerothcore

I'm trying to create a local server for a group of friends and applying some custom rules to accommodate the fact we're so few. One of the things I wish to do is enable free item trading, hence removing item bonding altogether.

I see that each item has a bonding row in the `item_template` table that determents its bonding status. Is there an easier way to make those items tradable without having to edit the rows directly into the database or use GM commands? I did not see an option in `worldsever.conf` so my guess is - no?

Moreover, what do the values in the bonding table mean? I found that 0 is no-bonding, 1 is bind on equip and 2 is bind on pick-up. But what are values 3, 4 and 5? Are those some special cases for quest items?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's the `item_template` table to change this.

See the wiki on https://azerothcore.org in the world-db section for details.

Answer (score 1):

It would require a core edit to item fetching to allow a setting like that, so your only course of action would be to write an SQL query to change the bonding of all of your items in the item_template table.